# is my understanding about dumpheap and gcroot not correct

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, windbg, sos

My understanding is that !dumpheap command list all the object present in the .NET heap that are not garbage collected. In that case if I run !gcroot command against an object address( found through !dumpheap -mt XXX) it should always give me stack trace of where that object is referenced. However I am finding examples where I canot find root of objects listed in !dumpheap. Is my understanding about !dumpheap and !gcroot not correct? If you want to see examples, its described in my other question posted [here](http://goo.gl/GqHVNh)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`!dumpheap` lists all objects on the managed heap. Some of these might be eligible for GC (i.e. they are not rooted). The latest version of SOS has `-live` and `-dead` flags to specifically list objects that can or cannot be reclaimed at this point.

Similarly, `!dumpheap` also lists "Free" objects, which are areas of the managed heap that have not been compacted yet. Sample output:

```
73113f80        1           84 System.Exception
008c4cb8        8           96      Free                <--- can be compacted at some point
731142a8        1          112 System.AppDomain
731169a4        1          132 System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo
731162dc        2          144 System.Globalization.CultureInfo
731141a0        2          168 System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
73116d54        2          280 System.Byte[]
73117684        3          468     System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.Type, mscorlib],    [System.Security.Policy.EvidenceTypeDescriptor, mscorlib]][]
731155f4       11          564 System.Int32[]
73116518        2          616 System.Globalization.CultureData
731147f8        4          718 System.Char[]
73115020       26          728 System.RuntimeType
73113e38      164         5502 System.String
730d0cdc       26        18152 System.Object[]
```

Comment: Can you give example of objects that will be on !dumpheap but will not list any reference with !gcroot

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want to see the output from `!gcroot` in case there is no roots for an object?

Comment: I am interested in #2 from your answer that are free objects but not compacted yet. These will be objects that have no reference anywhere and should have been removed from .net heap?

Comment: These are simply listed under the name "Free". They are not managed objects as such but simply areas of the managed heap that can be used for allocation.